# Firebase: Why I am getting service worker registration error

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am trying to implement push messaging using firebase. For this, I have followed google doc as well as script that google shared on github. You can find the same on below URL:

[Firebase Push Messaging Source Code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/bcce38ebc1e5602560e2b76b20f19b7834b8279e/messaging)

And also followed below tutorials:

[JS Setup from Google Tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

[How to Setup Push Messaging on Localhost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHgr5pQ_prw&list=PLCakfctNSHkGLCs9az_9PKqW1NY1C5HIU&index=2)

Below is my folder structure:

```
root
 |--push-demo
 |     |
 |     |--index.html
 |     |--index.js
 |
 |--firebase-messaging-sw.js
```

I have followed everything that describes in all the above links. As per requirement, I have also done following things:

1. Enable SSL on localhost
2. Put firebase-messaging-sw.js in root folder
3. Path for all the included JS files are correct. I mean when I open them in browser, browser is showing me JS content.
4. Generated VAPID key from firebase console and used the same.
5. Also enable allow-insecure-localhost in chrome

After doing everything correctly, I am getting below error:

**FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('https://localhost/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).**

Can someone please guide me about what is wrong at my side? I have looked many solutions on forums, and everyone is saying about either enable SSL on localhost or put your service file in root folder. But still I am getting error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you got any progress? I just hit the same wall

Comment: same situation , still suffer for a month  , please any new approach to deal with this annoying exception?